# Unable to pull / push through git with SSH in RStudio?

Tags: git, github, ssh, rstudio, ssh-keys

I'm not sure what the issue is, since I'd done this without a problem a long time ago.

Basically whenever I try to pull / push through the terminal or RStudio, I'm asked for my username and password (didn't use to be the case). When I supply them, I get an error message saying that this was disabled. It used to be that once my SSH public key was added to Github, things just worked.

I also tried `ssh -T git@github.com` it worked fine (I got the "Hi [username]! You've successfully authenticated [...]".

I've introduced myself to git, created new keys, registered them with the ssh agent--no luck.

Comment: *I'm asked for my username and password* - this means you are *not* using ssh, you are using https. Check the URL you assigned when you told RStudio to use a Git repository.

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal, check the URL used:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote -v
```

If it is an HTTPS one, and you want to use SSH:

```
cd /path/to/local/repository
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:MyAccount/MyRepository
```

Once that works from command-line, you can switch back to RStudio.